# How to open SQL Server Management Studio with pre-defined Server + Database selected + new blank Query open

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I use thousand times the SQL Server Management Studio during the day and I just found annoying
every time I open it to select the server, select the database and press new query...

I'm using windows integrated authentication

I would like to find a way to automatically set those up

I'm using the Studio from 2005

I'm not looking for "Why don't you keep it open instead" answer, please...

any tips?

Answer (score 2):

Try this (I'm using SSMS 2008):

1. Open properties window for your user and then change *default database* value to your desired one.
2. Go to `Tools/options/Environment/General` and select "Open new query window" inside "On startup"